# Taylor series approximation usage confusion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Hello Math Exchange!

I'm writing a short justification for gradient descent algorithm (nothing too rigorous, I'm a machine learning student) for my thesis, so in the course of reading up on it, I brushed up my Calculus and realized that certain things I took for granted don't make much sense to me upon closer examination.

If I understand correctly, Taylor expansion is an approximation that is correct at a point *a* and not necessarily around it. The logic goes that using it sometimes is preferable to due to non-computability of certain functions (e.g. certain functions expressed as integrals without a closed form), however what confuses me is this: (1) how can an approximation be useful outside of point *a* if it's only accurate at that point? Now, I understand that this isn't the case for certain expansions, and there exists a radius of convergence around which that approximation holds for $(a-r, a+r)$ (not sure if it's a closed or an open interval) and so that somewhat makes sense to me. But then (2) wouldn't it defeat the point of convenience of approximation to recompute the expansion for different blocks of points/intervals? I have a third basic question: suppose we have some approximation $h_1(x)$ for point *a*, then for all points $i \in [a-r, a+r]$ that lie in radius of convergence $r$ this $h(x)=f(x)$ holds, but if i were to recompute Taylor expansion calling it $h_2(x)$ around $i \neq a$ wouldn't all the points within radius $[i-r, i+r]$ also be accurate for $f(x)$ within that radius? (3) would that mean that within some subinterval there is an overlap of points where both $h_1$ and $h_2$ are accurate approximations of $f(x)$?

I want to clarify that I mean approximations in the limit of $n$, so not necessarily strictly equal to $f$ but equal within error range (if I recall it's big O of epsilon, but I'm not too sure).

Apologies if the question is too basic or needs more research done before being asked, but I find it easier to digest direct answers.